# running node application in Docker trough yarn

Tags: node.js, docker, yarnpkg, puppeteer

I am trying to create a docker image whose purpose is to expose as a uService the scraping of web pages by using yarn and micro.

My Docker file is as follows:

```
FROM cheeaun/puppeteer:latest
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash appuser
COPY . /app
RUN mkdir -p /app/logs
RUN mkdir -p /app/buffer
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install make -y
RUN apt-get install g++ -y
RUN cd /app && yarn --production --pure-lockfile
EXPOSE 3000   
USER appuser
WORKDIR /app
CMD ["su", "-", "user", "yarn", "start"]
```

Creating the image goes as expected:

```
docker build . -t <application-name>:<tag>
```

When I try to start a container from the image just created it stops immediately, inspecting the logs via
    docker logs f5fa9ba2e451

gives a discouraging:

```
su: must be run from a terminal
```

What I am doing wrong? TIA!

P.S. the question pointed out as a duplicate does not solve my problem as it refers to ssh-ing to the image, my problem is at start up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Dockerfile `USER` directive tells the image what user it should start up as.  You don't need to manually call `su` in your `CMD`; just remove it.

```
USER appuser
CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

Comment: Thanks! this solved the issue, I have another one now (chromium does not start inside the container) but the call goes as expected!